# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to mypackage.myclass

Tags: java, java-8, org.json

I have the following code in the Observable class:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("changedData", new MyClass());
```

I have the following in Observer class

```
MyClass a = (MyClass) data.get("changedData");
```

This works in my local environment, however in the evaluation environment I get an error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to mypackage.myclass
```

Can someone help me to understand in what case is `data.get("changedData")` referring to a HashMap?

Comment: I've run this exact code and it works fine. There's got to be something you're not showing us. Presumably at some point you're overwriting the key with a HashMap.

Comment: Is there anything in your evaluation environment that is kept in your JSONObject  with key as "changedData"

Comment: @Michael note that OP too has run this exact code and had it working fine. That is, until he deployed it to another environment.

Comment: Is using a debugger an option? It would help to make sure of the JSONObject's value and the JSON framework in use

Comment: @Aaron True, but there's nothing that can go wrong with those 3 statements. `JSONObject` simply maintains a `Map<String, Object>`. The other environment is almost certainly just going down another code path. We've been told nothing to suggest the scenarios were identical.

Comment: @Michael Since it works on my local, I don't really think so. I will try adding debug logs in case it has changed by anything else in the environment.

Comment: did your `Observable` & `Observer` are run in the same JVM? is `data` in `Observer` is deserialized from request? you haven't provided details of how your app deployed, so you need check it by yourself.